# How to animate the DIV to the center using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate

I have a div that covers the entire page `width=100%` and `height=100%`. I want usign `jquery.animate` to animate the div to horizontally center with a smaller width i.e 800px

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It all depends on your CSS and how flexible you are.

Here is an example of one way to do it:

http://jsfiddle.net/2Qxwn/

In this case, I position the `div` relative, and use jQuery to set the initial height/width to the width of the document.  I also set the `left` position to 50%, and the `margin-left` to half of the width (thus pulling it back to center).  I then animate the `width` and the `margin-left` accordingly.

You can also use the `margin: auto` method of centering, and then you only have to animate the width, but I am always leery of this method of centering:

http://jsfiddle.net/2Qxwn/1/

Comment: Awesome, Worked a treat! +1 for you ;)